# My project work is on time series using the ARMA model or the ARIMA model

Tags: time-series

My project work is on time series using the ARMA
model or the ARIMA model. Where do I start to analyze
my data?..... it is a federal road safety commision data from 2003-2014

Comment: tell us more about data.

Comment: federal road safety commission data

Comment: if you are satsified with my answer please provide an uptick and an acceptance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might start with the flow charts in http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/build-or-make-your-own-arima-forecasting-model . The classic 1960's version which assumed no deterministic structure is updated allowing for a composite model that includes seasonal dummies , level shifts , time trends and pulse detection/incorporation.  Care should be taken to understand that model identification is iterative and is not list-based . Model identification is not just fitting a large set of models and examining a simple statistic like AIC/BIC to determine "best" but rather a sequence of steps each examining the necessity and sufficiency of a current candidate model and developing/identifying needed improvements.

EDIT AFTER RECEIPT OF DATA :

Using a piece of software that I have helped develop (AUTOBOX) it started with a simple model [image] based upon [image] . It identified some unusual values and a seasonal pulse (December) and formed a final model [image] . The plot of the residuals suggests a possible change in variance (not found by the program ) [image] . The actual/fit and forecast plot is [image] a[image]nd the plot of the forecasts is here.

Comment: Thank you sir..... please I don't really understand were I can start, can I upload my data so you can help me sir

Comment: sure .... use an excel file format

Comment: sir please i can't find were to attach the Excel file... please can you help me with your email address so i can send it..plese

Comment: dave@autobox.com is the email address

Comment: Sir have sent it in your email